# Book series about these teenagers with special powers and every book changed main characters

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading this book back when I was in high school when I just first started out in 2012-2013. It was part of a series. I can't remember a whole lot about it. I believe the cover wasn't a hard cover but a flexible one and there was more than three books in the series.

It was about a group of teens that take a special class in high school for their special abilities and no one knows about their special abilities except for the teacher.  Pretty much a safe place for them.  Every new book changed the main character to another character from the classroom.

I can't remember what the teenagers (both genders) looked like but I know they were from all different social groups in high school and they did fight off bad people I think or some sort of evil. I believe one student had a power of shape shifting or taking over a body. One could read minds. One was able to become invisible. They were a part of this class to control their abilities too.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're not thinking about [Animorphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animorphs) right?

Comment: Possibly The Darkest Minds

Comment: Similar plot to what you're thinking about,just slightly different

Answer (score 5):

The ["Gifted"](https://www.goodreads.com/series/46405-gifted) series by Marilyn Kaye?

- [*Out of Sight, Out of Mind*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5602828-out-of-sight-out-of-mind)

  > Thirteen year old Queen-of-mean Amanda Beeson, wakes up one morning in the wrong body. She's become lonely, unfashionable Tracey Devon - one of Amanda's targets for bullying. Amanda discovers that Tracey, ignored at home and at school, has the ability to turn invisible. Amanda sets out to rescue her one-time victim from obscurity - as well as rescuing herself from Tracey's life.
- [*Better Late Than Never*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6303855-better-late-than-never)

  > Teenage goth and occasional rebel Jenna Kelly can read anyone's mind without even trying. When her alcoholic mother has to go into hospital, a stranger turns up who says he's her long-lost dad, and promises her a better future. While Jenna is happy to discover what it's like to have a proper parent, the gifted class have their concerns, but will Jenna listen?
- [*Here Today, Gone Tomorrow*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6505069-here-today-gone-tomorrow)

  > Shy, dreamy Emily's premonitions aren't always quite right, and even she does not trust them. But when her classmates start disappearing, someone has to listen.
- [*Finders Keepers*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7123179-finders-keepers)

  > Cute athletic Ken hears ghosts after a soccer collision takes out his best friend. When an anonymous note invites him to a seance, he want to confide in the convincing medium and find a $2M lottery ticket before the winning family gets evicted. Only his gifted classmates can save the day.
- [*Now You See Me*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7123181-now-you-see-me)

  > Who is the spy in the gifted class? Mean Amanda is out of character volunteering in the school office. Principal Mr Jackson finds/puts a knife in her locker and expels mind-reader Jenna to an institution with a corrupt aide. Now on her own investigating, Tracey turns invisible and lands in danger.
- [*Speak No Evil*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7830215-speak-no-evil)

  > Everyone in the gifted class has a secret, but Carter Street is the most mysterious student of all. He never speaks, and no one knows who he is or where he came from; they just know that like them, he's special. But there's something going on behind Carter's blank stare - something dangerous!